# Share data between phonegap and inappbrowser

Tags: javascript, cordova, window.open, inappbrowser

I'm doing a phonegap application and I cant share data between the index.html and the inappbrowser window. I try this code but it dont work for me.

```
function addUsuario(){
    var fnac = document.getElementById("fnac").value;
    var direccion = (document.getElementById("direccion").value).replace(/\s/g,'%20');
    var descripcion = (document.getElementById("descripcion").value).replace(/\s/g,'%20');
    //localStorage.setItem('"+direccion+"', direccion);


    var ref = window.open('./geo.html', '_blank');
    ref.addEventListener( "loadstart", function() {
    var dire=document.getElementById("direccion").value;
    ref.executeScript({ 
        code: "alert("+dire+");" 
    });
});

    setTimeout(function () {

        var lat = localStorage.getItem('lat');
        var lng = localStorage.getItem('lng');
        alert(lng);

        $('#datos').load("http://192.168.1.173/PHP_BS/mod_usuario.php?usuario=" + user + "&token=" + token+"&fnac="+fnac+"&dire="+direccion+"&descripcion="+descripcion+"&latitud="+lat+"&longitud="+lng);

        ref.close();
    }, 11500);


    }
```

I also try with the localStorage but only share data from inappbrowser to the index.js but not from the index.js to the inappbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

In your geo.html page:

```
<script>
  function onReceiveData (serialisedData) {
     var data = JSON.parse(serialisedData);
     alert('received some data!');
     console.log(data);
     // Do something with the data
  }
</script>
```

In your Cordova code:

```
var ref = window.open('./geo.html', '_blank');
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
    var params = {foo: 1};
    // Since executeScript works with a string, we need to serialise the data we send.
    ref.executeScript({code: "onReceiveData(" + JSON.stringify(params) + ")"});
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer but it dont work for me not event work the alert. I do all your steps.

Comment: Any errors or other information to debug the issue?

Comment: We're working with the mobile phonegap application and we use facebook to loggin in so we cant use the browser to debug. The only information we have is that dont work and the alert dont appear